# Checkbox values not submitted via POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

**My models**

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nom")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
}

public class ListUser
{
    public string ClickedButton { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public List<Models.User> Users;
}
```

**index.cshtml**

On this page I display all the users from `ListUser`, each user is selectable with a checkbox

```
@model Models.ListUser
<!-- some content here -->
<script>
    function clickedButton(i){
        document.getElementById("ClickedButton").value = i;
        return true;
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClickedButton);
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Users[i].IsSelected)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Users[i].Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Users[i].Name)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Users[i].Firstname)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Users[i].Firstname)
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Réinitialiser les mots de passe" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clickedButton('psw')"/>
}
```

And here's the controller (this controller is called when I submit the form)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ListUser model)
{
    // I added a breakpoint here            
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I want to send all the selected users to the controller, for instance when I select 4 users, I want to retrieve them in the controller :[image]

The problem : When I submit the form only the `ClickedButton` field is set in the model, the users I selected (via checkboxes) are not set.

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: what is this: `onclick="clickedButton('psw')`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I forgot to mention that, it sets the value of the hidden element `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClickedButton);`. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Users` is a field in your `ListUser` class, not a property, and the `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields. Change it to

```
public class ListUser
{
    public string ClickedButton { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public List<Models.User> Users { get; set; } // change
}
```

Note also that the only property that will be bound is the `IsSelected` property of `User`, and you will want to include a hidden input in the view for the `Id` property so that you an match up the correct selections

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Users[i].Id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Small change can help and be sure about all inputs have proper names in html form

```
public ActionResult Index(string ClickedButton, User model)
```